# How to install dependency libtagc0

Tags: beatbox

I want to install noise player (beatbox's fork player) on ubuntu 12.04, but when i try i get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 noise : Depends: libtagc0 (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

obviously I added the necesary ppa's

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemequ/sqlheavy
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install noise
```

but ubuntu does not have  libtagc0 installed, then i try to install libtagc0 with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtagc0-dev
```

but i got a error menssage:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libtagc0-dev
```

I've tried to fix the broken packages with:

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But any command didn't work! now i just do not know how can i install the dependency (libtagc0) to could install my favorite music player noise!

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Manual install can be an option. You can find the DEB on [ubuntuupdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/oneiric/main/base/libtagc0-dev). Use the `apt install` on the website. And after that try and install beatbox.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.

I've tried to install it manually but the software center showed me an error.
The package has unmet dependencies

So I could not install it!

Comment: install those too? Or use `dpkg`.